# Apply function over portion of dataframe multiple times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, filter

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: "Date" (in string format), "Hour" (in string format), "Energia_Attiva_Ingresso_Delta" and "Energia_Attiva_Uscita_Delta".
Obviously for every date there are multiple hours. I'd like to calculate a column for the overall dataframe, but on a daily base. Basically: the operation of the function must be calculated for every single date.
So, I thought to iter over the single values of the date column and to filter the dataframe with .loc, then pass the filtered df to the function. In the function I have to re-filter the df with loc (for the purpose of the calculation).
Here's the code I wrote and as you can see in the function i need to operate iterativelly on the row with the maximum value of 'Energia_Ingresso_Delta'; to do so I use again the .loc function:

```
#function
def optimize(df):
  min_index = np.argmin(df.Margine)
  max_index = np.argmax(df.Margine)
 
  Energia_Prelevata_Da_Rete = df[df.Margine < 0]['Margine'].sum().round(1)
  Energia_In_Eccesso = df[df.Margine > 0]['Margine'].sum().round(1)

  carico_medio = (Energia_In_Eccesso / df[df['Margine']<0]['Margine'].count()).round(1)

  while (Energia_In_Eccesso != 0): 
 
    max_index = np.argmax(df.Energia_Ingresso_Delta)

    df.loc[max_index, 'Energia_Attiva_Ingresso_Delta'] = df.loc[max_index,'Energia_Attiva_Ingresso_Delta'] + carico_medio

    Energia_In_Eccesso = (Energia_In_Eccesso - carico_medio).round(1)

#Call function with "partial dataframe". The dataframe is called "prova"
for items in list(prova.Data.unique()): 
  function(prova.loc[[items]])
```

But I keep getting this error:
"None of [Index(['2021-05-01'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
Can someone help me? :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide a data sample.

Comment: It could be due to the excess brackets; it should be "function(prova.loc[items])", not "function(prova.loc[[items]])"